# "parse error near `|'" when sourcing script file in zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm using zsh (5.4.2) with oh-my-zsh as my shell on Ubuntu 18.04.

The following script is executed correctly in zsh when I just run it (`./my_script -a 1`):

```
   #! /bin/bash
    
   while getopts "a:" OPTION; do
       case $OPTION in
       a)
           [[ ! $OPTARG =~ 1|2|3 ]] && {
               echo "Incorrect architecture provided"
           }
       esac
   done
   
  echo "End"
```

But when I'm sourcing it (`source ./my_script.sh -a 1`) zsh prints the following error: `parse error near '|'`.

What could be the possible reason?

Here is my .zshrc:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/home/ievgen.popovych/.oh-my-zsh"

ZSH_THEME="agnoster"

COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

plugins=(git colored-man-pages colorize command-not-found copydir copyfile cp dircycle dirpersist safe-paste tmux themes)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

export EDITOR='nvim'

# Setup dircolors
theme=ansi-light
eval `dircolors -b ~/dircolors-solarized/dircolors.$theme`

alias zshconfig="nvim ~/.zshrc"
alias gitconfig="nvim ~/.gitconfig"
alias nvconfig="nvim ~/.config/nvim/init.vim"
alias nvbundle="cd ~/.config/nvim/bundle && git clone "
alias nv="nvim"
alias debinstall="sudo dpkg -i "
alias zshr="source ~/.zshrc"
alias tmuxconfig="nvim ~/.tmux.conf"
alias cdbundle="cd ~/.config/nvim/bundle"

# git aliases
alias gs="git s"
alias gb="git b"
alias gco="git co"
alias gl="git l"
alias gp="git push"
alias gcreate="git create"
alias gamend="git amend"
alias gaa="git aa"
alias gfixup="git fixup"
alias gsquash="git squash"
alias gsymref="git symref"
```

Comment: For starters, you aren't using `zsh` when you use `./my_script`; you're using `bash`.

Comment: @EugenePopovych : I don't understand why you decdided to reveal your .zshrc, which is completely irrelevant to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

When you execute the script using `./my_script -a 1`, you aren't using `zsh`; you are using `bash`.

You can either escape the `|`

```
[[ ! $OPTARG =~ 1\|2\|3 ]]
[[ ! $OPTARG =~ "1|2|3" ]]
```

or store the regular expression in a variable

```
regex="1|2|3"
[[ ! $OPTARG =~ $regex ]]
```

The latter is necessary if you want the same code to work in both `bash` and `zsh`, but as a general rule writing code that works identically in both shells is more trouble than it is worth, assuming it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you really run your script under zsh, you have to use parenthesis when using alternatives in a regexp:

```
[[ ! $OPTARG =~ (1|2|3) ]]
```